# How to create a project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I installed the android studio successfully but any time I want to launch an new project (after naming the activity),I get an error message saying "can't resolve host at service.gradle.com" How do I resolve this?

Comment: Something appears to be wrong here. Gradle is hosted at `gradle.org`, NOT `gradle.com`. Also, there is no DNS entry for `service.gradle.org`, so this should probably be `services.gradle.org` instead.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a firewall of some sort is blocking Android Studio's connection to gradle. Check to make sure any antiviruses you have installed have Android Studio allowed through their firewall.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment instead of an answer (and something else is going on, as `gradle.com` is likely not what the OP wants).

Comment: @admdrew I actually can't comment yet :S I'm guessing OP didn't fully read the error message, and just copied the message wrong. Either way, sounds like OP's Android Studio can't access the internet.

Comment: `I actually can't comment yet` Right, which means you should work up your rep first. `sounds like OP's Android Studio can't access the internet` given the hostname "service.gradle.com" doesn't resolve for *anyone*, there is no evidence to suggest OP's connectivity is affected at all.

Comment: or as I said, OP might have been lazy in copying the error message. I've had people tell me a website was something.com when it's supposed to be .net or .org etc. In regards to working up first rep, that's what I'm trying to do by providing a possible solution to the problem with the information given. I know for a fact that Android Studio triggered a firewall warning when I first installed it, and if OP disallowed it, then Android Studio wouldn't be able to access "services.gradle.org" as it's supposed to, which would result in the host lookup failing.

Comment: `OP might have been lazy` Sure; that's when you ask for clarification, instead of posting an answer based on an assumption. `In regards to working up first rep` The fact that you can't yet comment doesn't make it ok to post a 'comment' as an answer, it just means you need to perform other actions on the site to boost your rep to allow you to use certain features.